# Entity Framework Core does not create join for related entities

Tags: exception, entity-framework-core, outer-join

I've created a couple of entities (Code First), a `User` and a `Configuration`. A user can have multiple configurations and each configuration has a single user.

```
public class ConfigurationDataContext : DbContext
{
    public ConfigurationDataContext(DbContextOptions options) 
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; init; }
    public DbSet<Configuration> Configurations { get; init; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        new User().OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        new Configuration().OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class User
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string? GivenName { get; set; }
    public string? FamilyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public ICollection<Configuration>? Configurations { get; init; }

    public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(e =>
        {
            e.HasIndex(new string[] { "FamilyName", "GivenName" });
            e.HasMany(e => e.Configurations).WithOne(e => e.Owner);
        });
    }
}

public class Configuration
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId? OwnerId { get; set; }

    public User? Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Configuration>(e =>
        {
            e.HasOne<User>("Owner").WithMany("Configurations")
             .HasForeignKey(c => c.Id).IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to retrieve the configuration data, I get the following exception:

> `` Field 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.TransparentIdentifierFactory+TransparentIdentifier`2[Configuration,User].Outer' is not defined for type 'Configuration' ``

To get my entity model:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var databaseName = "Simple-Configuration-test";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);

var db = new ConfigurationDataContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
                                        .UseMongoDB(client, databaseName).Options);

var user = new User() { GivenName = "test", FamilyName = "user" };

var existing = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.FamilyName == user.FamilyName && u.GivenName == user.GivenName);

if (existing == null)
{
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
else 
    user = existing;

Console.WriteLine($"User = {user.GivenName} {user.FamilyName} Created at {user.CreationDate}");

var configuration = new Configuration { Owner = user, OwnerId = user.Id };

var existingConfig = db.Configurations.Include(c => c.Owner).FirstOrDefault(c => c.OwnerId == user.Id);

if (existingConfig == null) 
    db.Configurations.Add(configuration);
else 
    configuration = existingConfig;

db.SaveChanges();

Console.WriteLine($"Configuration owner = {configuration!.Owner?.GivenName} {configuration.Owner?.FamilyName}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

The errant line of code:

```
var existingConfig = db.Configurations.Include(c => c.Owner).FirstOrDefault(c => c.OwnerId == user.Id);
```

I'm using the preview release of MongoDb.EntityFrameworkCore.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>mongo_example</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0-preview.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Maybe that is not the cause of the problem.

I'm expecting to be retrieve all `Configuration` entities along with their related `User` entity.

I've tried using both the fluent interface and property annotations to configure these entities, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This member of the Configuration model

```
    public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Configuration>(e =>
        {
            e.HasOne<User>("Owner").WithMany("Configurations")
             .HasForeignKey(c => c.Id).IsRequired();
        });
    }
```

SHOULD read

```
    public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Configuration>(e =>
        {
            e.HasOne<User>("Owner").WithMany("Configurations")
             .HasForeignKey(c => c.OwnerId).IsRequired();
        });
    }
```

In the original it was pointing to `Configuration.Id` as the foreign key, when it should have been pointing to `Configuration.OwnerId`.